# If statement for ranges in two separate worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, range

I have a worksheet with a column filled with numbers ranging from 1 to 4 and another column with company names.

I'm interested in having another worksheet where I only see campanies with a number of 3 or greater. Therefore, to make an IF statement that could do this, due to having a large and continously changing database. However, I keep getting an error for my proposed macro.

I hope there is someone that can help me.

```
Sub Simple_if()

Dim score As Integer, i As Long

i = 1

Do While Worksheets("Business").cells(i, "D").Value

score = Worksheets("Business").cells(i, "D").Value

If score >= 3 Then

Worksheets("Engagement Plan").cells(i, "A4").Value = Worksheets("Business").cells(i, "C").Value


End If
i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you think this means: `Do While Worksheets("Business").cells(i, "D").Value`?

Comment: Improve your question, which error do you get, you need to be more specific, what you tried etc.

Comment: Also, this: `Worksheets("Engagement Plan").cells(i, "A4")` should probably be `Worksheets("Engagement Plan").cells(i, "A")`

Comment: I keep getting an error that says 'type mismatch'? I can get it to work when I reference a specific cells, hvaing I want it to keep checking for values equal or greater to 3. It is suppose to be Worksheets("Engagement Plan").cells(i, "A4"), since I want it to start from A4 and downwards. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Simple_if()
 Dim shB As Worksheet, shE As Worksheet, lastRB As Long
 Dim score As Integer, i As Long, k As Long, arrB, arrE

 Set shB = Worksheets("Business")
 Set shE = Worksheets("Engagement Plan")
 lastRB = shB.Range("D" & shB.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

 arrB = shB.Range("C1:D" & lastRB).Value 'put the shB sheet range in an array
 ReDim arrE(UBound(arrB))      'redim arrE at maximum possible dimension

 For i = 1 To UBound(arrB)
    If arrB(i, 2) >= 3 Then
        arrE(k) = arrB(i, 1) 'fill arrE only with elements >=3
        k = k + 1
    End If
 Next i
 ReDim Preserve arrE(k - 1)  'redim the array to keep only the filled elements

 'drop the array content at once:
 shE.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrE) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrE)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! I tried the code and I get an error saying 'Subscript out of range'.

Comment: Is this a code line...? I will adapt the answer, anyhow...

Comment: There was no error this time, but nothing happened either. No company names were populated in the 'Engagement plan' worksheet.

Comment: @Anders Vigen: Did you adapt the code to your worksheets, or run it as it is? I used active sheet and the next one... I will adapt it...

Comment: If "Business" sheet was the active one, the code returned in the next one. You can check that. If not "Business" sheet was the active one, it processed the active one. I think this simple things should be observed and solved by you... Do you understand the code logic?

Comment: It completely works now! I didn't detected it wasn't adapted to my sheet, I can easily see that now. My bad. I think I need to use some time trying to understand it. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Anders Vigen: Glad I could help! The purpose of our community is to make people learn, not receiving code solutions... And something else: We here, when somebody answer our question, thick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...